# Is it able to test phonegap application outside emulator?

Tags: cordova, emulation

When develop a phonegap application, it sometimes need to deploy the application to an android emulator to test it. It's not convenient sometimes.

Is there any tool to test a phonegap application outside emulator? For example some browser plugins for desktop browsers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ripple emulator lets you test your phonegap app inside chrome with a chrome plugin.

Here is the plugin in the chrome web store: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc

And here is the ripple homepage:
https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/download/ripple

If you want local file access you have to do two things:

1. start chrome with --allow-file-access-from-files flag
2. go to chromes extensions page, find the ripple plugin, check the 'Allow access to file URLs' checkbox

Comment: If my phonegap app has some native operation, e.g. load or write some local files, is it working fine with ripple?